# iOS enterprise application: if I add entitlement to bundle ID, will that invalidate existing apps in the field?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, enterprise, entitlements

I have an iOS enterprise-signed app in the field which is chugging along fine. I'd like to add an additional entitlement, which means adding that entitlement to the registered bundle ID in the Apple Developer Portal then creating a new provisioning profile. Can anyone confirm that adding a new entitlement to the bundle ID won't invalidate existing, working apps in the field, signed by an earlier provisioning profile?
Many thanks

Comment: The provisioning profile is "baked in" to the installed app. Updating a provisioning profile won't impact any already installed apps.

Comment: That I understand, but the change is also being made to the bundle ID - I'm not sure if iOS makes a check with apple regarding capabilities attached to the bundle ID

Comment: No. The provisioning profile in the installed bundle is what is checked. At some point that embedded provisioning profile will expire and you users will need to install a new build with your updated provisioning profile. The installed app does need to periodically check that your enterprise program is still in good standing, so it needs Internet access, but it doesn't have any way of accessing the provisioning profile that is un your developer account.

Comment: FYI, this is not what Apple says from their developer support response  to me - They said that adding an entitlement to the bundle ID will cause the provisioning profile already deployed in the field to become invalid and that will tank already distributed apps.

Comment: I guess you could easily test it by creating another simple app, installing it and then changing the provisioning profile for it, but Apple's answer doesn't match my understanding of how provisioning profiles are embedded

Comment: So, I've had incorrect answers before from developer support relating to enterprise application development and deployment, on one occasion on a phone call, I really felt the person didn't understand what they were talking about. A few days later, presumably after reviewing the phone call recording, they phoned back to say that they were incorrect. Yes, I could easily test and I probably will. Thanks.

Comment: There was a great video from wwdc 2014 that explained how enterprise provisioning profiles worked, but it seems to have been vaporised by Apple.

Comment: @Nostradamus Can you please share your update on this? It will be really helpful for me, now I need to enable entitlement for com.apple.developer.device-information.user-assigned-device-name. It throws a warning for invalidating existing profiles, i'm worrying about existing live apps.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any firm advice. I believe the response from Apple was incorrect (I've had incorrect responses from Apple Developer support before), but the enterprise team I work with wasn't prepared to take the risk and they would rather create a whole new bundle ID.